# How to use SharedSizeScope between 2 wpf controls with parent child relation?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a scenario where i have one control, which is using another control thru ListBox.ItemTemplate. I need to share Height and width between these 2 controls. How can we achieve that?

Main Conrol Xaml looks like as followings:

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                   Text="{Binding Path=Caption,
                                  Mode=OneWay}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                   Text="{Binding Path=Caption2,
                                  Mode=OneWay}" />
    </Grid>

    <ListBox Grid.Row="0"
             Grid.Column="1"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ViewModels}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Views:View2 />
            </DataTemplate>

  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

View2 xaml looks like as following:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
               Grid.Column="0"
               Text="{Binding Path=Value,
                              Mode=OneWay}"/>


    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=Value2,
                              Mode=OneWay}"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                               />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can synchronize row height and column width using `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope` and the `SharedSizeGroup` attribute on `ColumnDefinition` and `RowDefinition`.

I'm not sure which elements you need to synchronize in your Xaml, but an example might be as follows:

Ia a parent element you use *Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"*

```
<Grid IsSharedSizeScope="true">
   ..
</Grid>
```

This synchronizes any columns (or rows) that have the same SharedSizeGroup within that scope (you can have multiple nested scopes).

So if your view.xaml looks like this

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="column1"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value2, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
</Grid>
```

Then all the textblocks will have the same width.